# PHP Git Pull from GitHub Script SSH

Tags: php, git, github, ssh

This is the first time I've tried to use the GitHub service hooks to automatically deploy to my server; and after slowly working my way over every obstacle it looks like the very last one is the one that has done me in.

The initial clone of my git repository onto my web server was done through SSH, and I'm pretty sure that has something to do with my problems now. My current script is the basic:

```
<?php 
    echo(shell_exec('git pull 2>&1')); 
?>
```

But it returns "Permission denied (publickey). fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"; which I know is where the script is failing to put in the SSH pass phrase I created. I tried doing research on how to maybe get past it, but I don't even know if those would be the correct/securest things to do.

So can this be modified to work from here or do I need to backtrack a few steps and step away from using SSH to begin with?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace (in your git.config file )

```
ssh://github.com/<username>/<project>.git
```

or

```
https://github.com/<username>/<project>.git
```

with

```
git@github.com:<username>/<project>
```

Comment: That is currently what the remote origin is set to.

Answer (score 0):

Apache is probably running as a different user than the one you normally run git with via the CLI. You'll probably need to copy your `.ssh/id_rsa` file from `/home/regularuser/` to `/home/webuser/`.

Comment: The ssh is within /.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: So both users already have the same SSH private keys in their .ssh/id_rsa file?

Comment: I do not have access to multiple users; everything is just within home. I can ssh into the server from CLI and run the Git Pull. That produces the same results as executing Git Pull from the server itself. Either one requests the input of the pass phrase, but only one of them can I actually input it.